# Using Strtok() on a Dynamically allocated array

Tags: c

For example, if I am trying to taken in user input dynamically. When trying to display each of the words entered by the user, only one word appears.

Sample code:

```
int main() {
  char* x;

  printf("Enter message: ");
  scanf("%ms", &x);

  char* token = strtok(x, " ");

  while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  free(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter message: x y z
x
```

Comment: In all my years, I have never seen `%ms` before, didn't know it existed.  It is certainly not a standard feature, so it must be a vendor extension.

Comment: It automatically dynamically allocates a string, was able to learn that from some sample code.

Comment: If you print `x` before parsing it with `strtok()`, you are likely to see that `scanf()` is reading only 1 single word at a time, as `%s` stops reading on whitespace.  That would explain the behavior you are seeing. Try `fgets()` instead.

Comment: I dont think %ms is a vendor extension, seems like a default thing

Comment: It is not standard, it is an extension ([according to opengroup.org](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html)). Some platforms, like Linux, implement it.  Other platforms, like Windows, do not.

Comment: I though it was supposed to print 1 single word at a time. And for printing out all the token I got help from here https://www.educative.io/edpresso/splitting-a-string-using-strtok-in-c

Comment: Yes, `strtok()` will do that, if you give it a multi-word string to begin with. But you are not. If the user types `x y x`, `scanf("%ms")` will return only `"x"`, not `"x y z"` like you are expecting. Thus, you call `strtok("x", " ")` which returns `"x"`, and then call `strtok(NULL, " ")` which returns NULL. That is the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the call to `scanf`.  The `%ms` format stops when it encounters white space.  If you print `x` immediately after the `scanf` call, you'll see it contains only the first word, so there's nothing else for `strtok` to find.

You can fix it by changing the `scanf` format as follows:

```
  scanf("%m[^\n]", &x);
```

This will still do the buffer allocation for you, but it will read characters until it encounters a newline (at least on Unix - not sure what this will do on Windows).

Alternatively, you could use `getline`.  Or you could use`fgets`, but you'd have to do the buffer allocation yourself.  Note that these would both include the newline.